# How can I disable all or most cloud based connections/services in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10-preview

I don't want my machine running Windows 10 to connect to any Microsoft (or other) cloud based service, except Windows Update.

How can I selectively disable connection to any cloud servers?

Are there registry settings available? Do I need to edit the hosts file?

Which entries would I have to add?

Comment: Just don't connect your local account to a Microsoft Account

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per Ramhound's suggestion, using a local account and not a Microsoft account when your computer is first installed will prevent most Microsoft cloud services ever being active. This is probably the safest, cleanest, and easiest way.